# How to match a regex pattern but return None if additional characters are in string?

Tags: python, regex

I would like to check if a string is of the following regex structure: `[0-9]+-[0-9]+`

I have the following Python code which, unfortunately, also returns a match when my input string includes the defined pattern and additional characters:

```
import re

my_string = '100-300'
re.match(r'[0-9]+-[0-9]+', my_string)    # returns a match as desired

my_string = 'abc100-300cyd'
re.match(r'[0-9]+-[0-9]+', my_string)    # also returns a match
```

How can I extend my pattern matching so that I only get a match when the pattern is matched and no additional characters are present?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place a `^` for the beginning of a line and a `$` for the end like

```
^[0-9]+-[0-9]+$
```

EDIT: As @Wiktor noticed, the full match of a complete line does not work on a complete string if it contains line breaks. So you would have to test for line breaks regardless of the programming language or use `re.fullmatch`.

Comment: No need for `^` and `$` that do not ensure full string match in Python. Try it in `re.search(r'^[0-9]+-[0-9]+$', '12-34\n')` and you will get a match. The right answer is "use `re.fullmatch`".